# How to completely remove Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, installation, dual-boot, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu using Wubi installer, but I couldnt boot to it. So I uninstalled it on the Control Panel. Then I tried the full installation wherein it boots to the Ubuntu environment. After installing Ubuntu there, I couldnt boot to my Windows 7 anymore! So in an attempt to salvage the whole thing, I inserted the Ubuntu CD again and chose Erase Ubuntu and Reinstall. (I was wondering, why wasn't there an option to just "Erase Ubuntu"?) I did that though, and I got my Windows 7 back. But upon checking my drives via the "Create your own partition scheme" (not sure if it's the exact words) I saw that one of my partitions still has Ubuntu on it, and there's no way I can delete it if I don't overwrite another Ubuntu! I can't access that partition on windows 7 either! Need help!

Comment: post the output of bootinfoscript http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is only about the partition. Linux use ext2/3 file system and Windows doesn't support that file system, so normally you cannot see the drive which format in ext2/3 on Windows. My suggestion here is you can use PartitionMagic (or any tool works with partition), erase that drive and merge it to another fat32/ntfs drive, so you can retrieve it completely

Comment: No need of 3rd party tool. You can delete the drive and extend other partition using disk management utility. run "diskmgmt.msc" in windows run  prompt (press Win + R)

Comment: If you are still getting the menu giving you an option of what to boot you are probably using some of the contents of that Ubuntu partition to get that menu to work. Here are some instructions: http://askubuntu.com/a/143482/63886. In particular you need to replace the MBR which will allow you to boot directly into Windows. After that you can use Windows tools to delete the Ubuntu partition and maybe merge the space back into a Windows partition.