# How to install Windows 7 after Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to completely remove Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119746/how-to-completely-remove-ubuntu)

I installed Ubuntu to see what it is..
well I saw and its far to complicated and annoying to me..
or maybe I just looked at it wrong I m still open for ideas..

but I tried  to install w7 and when I got to choose the Partition select it says that it can install w7 only on NTFS disc and I have some other type..
what is it and how can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

It's really off topic for this site, but ok. The windows installer has the ability to delete filesystems. I don't remember exactly how, though. I'd guess you see something like "Unknown" with a certain size. That's likely Ubuntus filesystem. Delete it, create a new one and install.